# ¿Cómo hacer un query a un campo Pointer con el ID del objeto?

Tags: javascript, ionic, parse.com

Tengo un `state` en el que estoy pasándo el ID de mi clase `Category`:

```
.state('app.create-chambba', {
  cache: false,
  url: "/services/create-chambba/:categoryId",
  views: {
    "menuContent": {
      templateUrl: "views/app/services/create_chambba.html",
      controller: "CreateChambbaCtrl"
    }
  }
})
```

El tema es que en mi controlador `CreateChambbaCtrl` pensé que podría usar el `categoryId` para obtener todas las sub-categorías que pertenecen a esa categoría. Algo así:

```
var SubCategory = Parse.Object.extend("SubCategory");
var query = new Parse.Query(SubCategory);
query.equalTo("isActive", true);
query.equalTo("categoryId", $stateParams.categoryId); // El ID de categoría
query.ascending("name");
query.find(...);
```

Pero haciéndolo de esa forma me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
message: "pointer field categoryId needs a pointer value"
```

Entonces, decidí primero hacer un query a la categoría para obtener el objeto y luego con ese objeto obtener las sub-categorías:

```
var Category = Parse.Object.extend("Category");
var queryCategory = new Parse.Query(Category);
queryCategory.equalTo("objectId", $stateParams.categoryId);
queryCategory.first({
    success: function(category) {
        var SubCategory = Parse.Object.extend("SubCategory");
        var query = new Parse.Query(SubCategory);
        query.equalTo("isActive", true);
        query.equalTo("categoryId", category);
        query.ascending("name");
        query.find(..);
    }
});
```

De alguna manera siento que estoy haciendo trabajo extra, ¿existe una mejor forma?

---

[Cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34832885/688393) en Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta de [Alon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160197/alon) en el [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34832885/688393) de Stack Overflow

---

Crea un objeto nuevo de `Category` y asigna al ID del objeto al ID que quieres buscar:

```
var categoria = new Category();  
categoria.id = $stateParams.categoryId; 
....
```

Y usa el objeto como un `Pointer`:

```
query.equalTo("categoryId", categoria);
```

Es un pequeño truco pero debería resolver tu problema.