# Hacer referencia a un valor de tipo Pointer en Swift con Parse

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode, parse.com

Tengo creados en parse varias clases y muchas de ellas relacionadas entre si por Pointers. Un ejemplo es el siguiente.

Tengo 2 clases:

- `subcategorias`
- `comercios`

En `comercios` yo puedo tener registros de muchos comercios, ahi hay un campo llamado `come_subc_id` y está ligado a la clase `subcategorias` por medio de un Pointer.

En la clase `subcategorias` tengo una clasificación de todos los comercios, es decir si es un hotel, una restaurant, lavandería, etc.

Tengo una `PFQueryTableViewController` donde pretendo mostrar una relación de por ejemplo todos los hoteles.

Si en mi clase `subcategorias` por ejm  el `objectId` de hoteles es `gL8qGBhXMI`, ¿cómo puedo generar la consulta para que me muestre solamente en la tabla todos los hoteles que tengo registrados en la clase comercios? Mi duda es,¿cómo puedo generar una consulta de una clase accediendo a los campos de otra clase por medio del pointer?. Lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera, pero con errores y tengo el siguiente código y aun no puedo refinarlo y desconozco si estoy yendo en el rumbo correcto.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
let queryHot = PFQuery(className: "comercios") //El que funciona
        queryHot.includeKey("come_subc_id") //Tipo pointer apuntando a clase subcategorias
        queryHot.whereKey("come_subc_id", equalTo: "gL8qGBhXMI") // comparando si el registro tiene clasificacion de hotel
return queryHot
}
```

Al ejecutar la aplicación me arroja el siguiente error:

```
2016-01-24 14:05:35.579 AppBeta1[1045:35017] [Error]: pointer field come_subc_id needs a pointer value (Code: 102, Version: 1.11.0)
```

Entiendo que el error se genera en la consulta cuando hago la comparación:

```
queryHot.whereKey("come_subc_id", equalTo: "gL8qGBhXMI")
```

Puesto que el campo `come_subc_id` no es de tipo `string` si no que es un objeto, mi pregunta es sobre como implementar el método correcto para realizar esta comparación, si logro entender esta parte prácticamente podré realizar todas las consultas que se generan en mi aplicación ya que todas las clases estan relacionadas por Pointers.

Si no he sido del todo claro puedo replantear mi problema.

Agradezco su apoyo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mi me pasó algo parecido pero usando JavaScript, al parecer Parse no acepta que le pases cadenas como Pointers, tienes que pasarle un objeto.

La solución es que al hacer el query, uses un objeto en la parte del `equalTo`. No se absolutamente nada de Swift pero, ayudándome de la documentación, supongo que algo como esto podría funcionar:

```
# ...
PFObject *subcategoria = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"subcategorias"];
subcategoria[@"id"] = @"gL8qGBhXMI";
queryHot.whereKey("come_subc_id", equalTo: subcategoria)
# ...
```

Espero que el código sea correcto pero la idea es similar a la respuesta que me fue dada en mi pregunta [¿Cómo hacer un query a un campo Pointer con el ID del objeto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2607/100).

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias Cesar Bustios por la guia.

Efectivamente lo tuve que adaptar para swift y ha quedado asi:

```
let queryHot = PFQuery(className: "comercios") //Clase
            let hotel : String = "gL8qGBhXMI"
            let pointer = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"subcategorias", objectId: hotel)
            print(pointer)
            queryHot.includeKey("come_subc_id")
            queryHot.whereKey("come_subc_id", equalTo:pointer)
```

Ha funcionado!!!

Comment: Hola Victor, nos alegra haberte ayudado a resolver tu problema, aqui en SO en español tenemos algunos pequeños lineamientos para que el sitio sea mas claro, para quien pregunta, responde y visita a diario, podrias marcar la respuesta de **Cesar** con el boton en forma de V para que alguien mas sepa que fue lo correcto, y si quieres agregar mas detalles, prueba editando la respuesta de Cesar y agregar esto ahi, asi podras ayudar a futuros usuarios ;)

Comment: Está bien que añadas una respuesta con la adaptación que has hecho de la respuesta de César. Pero como se te ha sugerido, deberías marcar su respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: Enterado. Ya esta hecho. Una disculpa soy nuevo en esto!